# Issue with Kotlin Gradle plugin in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I just upgrade Android studio to the last version (3.2.1) and an issue occurred while charging my project. The Kotlin Gradle plugin seems to be incompatible with the current Android Gradle plugin version, or something like that.

Here's the message displayed:

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'Projetpelican' is using version 1.2.41.

I can't find any satisfying answer on the web so please enlight me with your knowledge.

PS. A similar topic had already been created but it does not fully answer the question...

Answer (score 3):

in your build gradle
change 1.2.41 to following

```
         buildscript {
                   ext {
                     kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score -1):

Update your Kotlin version.

Under your project-level `build.gradle` (the one *outside* of the `app` folder), find the `ext.kotlin_version` variable and set it to `'1.3.11'`.

When maintaining an Android project, you need to keep an eye out for yellow-highlighted dependencies. Android Studio doesn't update them for you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I can't find the `ext.kotlin_version`, it is not in my `build.gradle` file. Therefore there is a yellow-highlighted dependencie : `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'`.

Comment: Not your app build.gradle, your _project_ build.gradle.

Comment: That is not in the app build.gradle.

Comment: You have dependencies on your project build.gradle? If there are no lines beginning with `classspath` then you have the wrong file.

Comment: Ok I got it. Sorry I thought I was selecting the right document but I wasn't selecting anything at all ... So I changed the `ext.kotlin_version` vriable to `1.3.11` but it's not working. I get another error.
Well ... thank you for helping me :)

Comment: It would be nice if (a) Android Studio would make the upgrade itself, or at least (b) provide a link to the correct file; i.e., the project's `build.gradle`. The error message provides a link to the app's `build.gradle` which is completely useless.

Comment: @JohnPerry Kotlin has a classpath and an implementation, one for the project and one for the module (app). They both use the same version, so the configuration extracts it to a variable that both reference. Technically, it _did_ take you to the right file. As for automatic updates when required, well Kotlin is still kind of new.

Comment: @TheWanderer I wouldn't say it took me to the right file, not even technically. `ext.kotlin.version` doesn't appear in the file at all. If Android Studio can be smart enough to do half the things it does, surely it can be smart enough to provide a link to the file where the definition of a constant actually appears.

Comment: @JohnPerry the dependency in question is in the module config, while the version is defined in the project. AS just knows where the dependency is, not where its version is defined (it's also usually defined right inline instead of in a variable). It is annoying that you can't Ctrl+Click to follow the variable, but that's a Gradle problem.